# In Hyperledger Fabric, does a client send a transaction to all orders or only to one orderer node?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, consensus

When a client orders a transaction, does he send it to all the orderers (like in PBFT) or only to one/few orderers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: "It depends".

In Fabric, the consensus mechanism is pluggable, and as a result - anyone can implement its own ordering service as long as it implements the [AtomicBroadcast](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.4/protos/orderer/ab.proto) gRPC API:

```
service AtomicBroadcast {
    // broadcast receives a reply of Acknowledgement for each common.Envelope in order, indicating success or type of failure
    rpc Broadcast(stream common.Envelope) returns (stream BroadcastResponse) {}

    // deliver first requires an Envelope of type DELIVER_SEEK_INFO with Payload data as a mashaled SeekInfo message, then a stream of block replies is received.
    rpc Deliver(stream common.Envelope) returns (stream DeliverResponse) {}
}
```

If the consensus service is of a CFT type, like Kafka or Raft - then the client needs to send a transaction only to a single orderer.

However, there are [unofficial implementations](https://github.com/SmartBFT-Go/fabric) of Byzantine Fault Tolerant consensus service for Hyperledger Fabric out there, and in these implementations the client cannot assume that the selected orderer will honestly include its transaction, therefore it would need to send the request to all nodes as in the PBFT paper.

When Fabric will have an official BFT orderer then the client would need to be configured appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am trying to implement a version of BFT for fabric. Can you please guide me and give resources for the same. Thanks

Comment: look at the link in my answer